# Error when trying to refactor-rename in XCode 4.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, ios4

i can't refactor->rename any class on my project because I receive the message "The selection is not a type that can be renamed. Make a different selection and try again.". This don't happens if I create a new project and try to rename some class but in my working project it always happens. Is it a bug?

Comment: XCode refactoring tools are pants! Up until 4.0 you could only do renames, and not very well. They're thrown a few more in the recent releases. IntelliJ was excellent for refactoring - and now JetBrains have an Xcode alternative: AppCode - i've tried it and it works great, and it has all the great refactoring tools I remember - and they work! Can't bring myself to leave Xcode though - i like it.

Comment: I've met this too
[Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701343/xcode-5-0-2-failed-to-launch-cocoa-touch-tool/29553853#29553853)

Answer (score 3):

Is the project stored in Dropbox? If so, take it out. If not, is there anything peculiar about the folder the project is in? It seems other people have had this issue when storing projects in Dropbox.

Comment: It isn't stored in Dropbox. There is only project files and hg files for versioning.

Comment: DropBox thing did it for me.

Comment: Damn dropbox mangles it again. I've had so many files mangled in dropbox.