# Xcode 5.0.2 : Failed to Launch Cocoa Touch Tool...?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode5

I've been trying to do some programming with Xcode 5, but I've been having some problems. I'm trying to create a new Objective-C Class from File > New File. I can create the class, but a few seconds after it's been created, Xcode crashes and gives me an error. I tried this 3 times, and got the same error. I put the error as well as my console log for it here:

Error: http://www.pastebin.com/PmdZaDag
Console Log: http://www.pastebin.com/5sCmcurW

I don't really know much about programming in Xcode, so I'm not sure what the problem is at all. Thanks!

Xcode 5.0.2
MacBook Pro Retina with OS X 10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems like in your Xcode 5.0.2. Tried with higher version or install the same version of Xcode again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too .

Here is my solution:

1. create a new .storyboard file
2. right click these two .storyboard file respectively Open As >> Source Code
3. According to the new .storyboard file , change the `version` and `toolsVersion` Tag